# How can be retrieved the address of the struct array?

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to read out a text file and store the data in a struct array, however I am getting a segmentation fault. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[24];
    unsigned short value;
}Flags;

int ReadData(char * filename, Flags* retv){

    //First getting the number of lines, this helps to allocate the memory for the struct    
    char line[255];
    int linenr = 0;    
    char* token;    

    FILE* myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    while(!feof(myfile))
    {
        char ch = fgetc(myfile);
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            linenr++;
        }
    }
    retv = malloc(linenr * sizeof(Flags));    
    linenr = 0; 

    // Bring the file pointer to the beginning
    rewind(myfile); 

    // Read data line by line
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), myfile)) {                
        token = strtok(line, "="); 
        if (token != NULL){            
            strcpy(retv[linenr].name, token);


            // Getting the value
            token = strtok(NULL, "=");
            if (token != NULL)
                retv[linenr].value = atoi(token);
            else
                retv[linenr].value = 0;

            // Debugging
#ifdef DEBUG           
            printf("i: %d\n", linenr);
            printf("Name: %s\n", retv[linenr].name);        
            printf("Value: %d\n", retv[linenr].value);       
#endif
            linenr ++;         
        }   
    }

    fclose(myfile);

    return linenr;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Flags * values;
    int linenr = 0;
    int i;

    // Read the data
    linenr = ReadData("test.txt", values);

    // Some debugging
    printf("Line number: %d\n", linenr);

    for (i = 0; i < linenr; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        printf("Name: %s\n", values[i].name);
        printf("Value: %d\n", values[i].value);
    }    
    free(values);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
i: 0
Name: fa_flag 
Value: 0
i: 1
Name: s2s_flag 
Value: 12
i: 2
Name: torque_flag 
Value: 1
i: 3
Name: torque_flag2 
Value: 1
i: 4
Name: torque_flag3 
Value: 1
Line number: 5
i: 0
Name: (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I couldn't figure it out where did I make the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int ReadData(char * filename, Flags* retv){
    ....
    retv = malloc(linenr * sizeof(Flags));
```

The memory gets allocated correctly, but the pointer in `main` is not updated.

```
Flags * values;
....
linenr = ReadData("test.txt", values);
```

Change it to:

```
int ReadData(char * filename, Flags** retv){
    ....
    *retv = malloc(linenr * sizeof(Flags));
```

and

```
Flags * values;
....
linenr = ReadData("test.txt", &values);
```

Comment: The solution is working, thanks. I am just wondering, the values is already a pointer, why is not updated?

Comment: The pointer is passed by value, inside `ReadData` you have the same 'value' (address) than the pointer in `main` had, but it is a copy, so the pointer in `main` is not updated.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is clearer: If you would allocate memory in `main` and pass a pointer to `ReadData`, then you would see the changes made by `ReadData` to that memory in main. But here you're not changing the memory, you're changing the pointer itself (where it points to).